Simplest way to send data from a google form to a MySQL database?
I am looking to create a MySQL database which stores information which is coming from a google form.
I was thinking of having the google form results stored in google sheets and then using JDBC to send the google sheets contents to the database. Must the database be hosted in order for this to function? Is there an easier way to do this? Sorry I'm pretty new to this.
Thanks.

search for how to connect google form to mysql database . - this question is likely to be closed because it is not about programming or software development. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Must the database be hosted in order for this to function? This is a very common question and there are many (consistent) answers on StackOverflow. I suggest reading Connect Google Sheet to localhost MySQL with JDBC Services and specifically the Comments by @NightEye.

This question is similar to: Connect Google Sheet to localhost MySQL with JDBC Services. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Is there an easier way to do this? You are asking for advice and that is off-topic on StackOverflow.
